# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

So I'm trying to fetch data from another service and convert it as object, and get the specific property by ID for example, but the problem is that my data seems like it's undefined, maybe the syntax is wrong? But I wouldn't say that...

```
app.get ('/products&comments/:title', async (req , res) => {
    
    const title = req.params.title;
    
    const db = await connect();

    const doc = await db.collection("posts").findOne({title: title});
    
    
    const { comments } = await axios.get("http://localhost:4201/comments");
    
    const singleProductComment = await comments.find((comments) => comments.postID === doc._id);

    console.log(singleProductComment)

   res.json(singleProductComment)


});
```

What could be wrong, isn't this syntax `const singleProductComment = await comments.find((comments) => comments.postID === doc._id);` good?

The full error message:

[image]

Console.log(comments) output:

[image]

Comment: why not implement `/comments?postId=` in the api? seems inefficient to get all comments then filter them after the fact, if its not your API then you should at least add caching

Comment: How do you mean exactly? `http://localhost:4201/comments?postId=doc._id`? something like that?

Comment: yeah so it filters the comments by post id, if it was a specific comment you wanted to find it would be `/comments/123`, I'm just pointing out that its not ideal to fetch all comments, imaging you had 100k comments and then perhaps 10 people on your site at once, the server would be pulling a million things only to fetch 10 not to mention that say 1 comment is 100bytes of json, is like 10MB per request to the API, you should offload as much as you can and just pass params

Comment: I know roughly what you are trying to say, can you add that more precisely in answer to my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop variable name 'comments' is the same as the array variable name 'comments', also you don't need to await before find.

```
 **comments**.find((**comments**) => **comments**.postID === doc._id);
```

should be:

```
comments.find((comment) => comment.postID === doc._id);
```

here:      `comments =  [comment, comment, comment, comment];`

Comment: Okay, I did that, removed await and looped the variable name `comment`, but I'm still facing the same error undefined of 'find()'

Comment: And if I `console log` comments I'm getting the normal output, normal values

Comment: Also check if "comments" is an array and not object.

Comment: I updated full error message in a question

Comment: What if it is an array? How to just convert it as a JSON object?

Comment: Comments must be null so u cant operate  on null or undefined.

Comment: Also we want comments to be an array.

Comment: Comments are undefined when I try to console it, so how to do that exactly? Can you update your answer?

Comment: I cant update it, your question was about “ find “, but your await axios.get("http://localhost:4201/comments"); should be returning something that u can iterate over.

Comment: Btw why using “const { comments }” instead of “ const comments”, look at its value and proceed accordingly

Comment: My axios.get is returning data, but it seems it's not returning the data on this way while using `{}`, if I use `const comments` then how do I sort it with `find()` like that: `comments.postID === doc._id`?

Comment: What is value of comments with “let commets”?

Comment: I updated my console.log output of "let comments"

Comment: Then dont u get values when u do comments.data.find

Comment: I updated my console.log output in the question, it maybe helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236765/discussion-between-jan-tudan-and-vaira).